# Websockets: one channel with all the users or one channel per user?

Tags: websocket

I want to implement websocket-based push notifications in a website. I already serached here on SO and on google, but my question is a bit different.
My use-case:
when userB replies to a comment posted by userA, userA will receive a push notification with a link to the article/comment (It is similar to SO)
My research:
on the web, people seem to agree that (in terms of scalability) it is better to limit the total amount of websocket channels. That leads to 1 channel per every user (= each channel will only contain 1 user). Why? Think about a group chat where 1 user could participate in 10 or more discussions --> that would mean 10 or more channels per user.
So, 1 channel per user is the best solution (until now).

I plan on using this bundle https://github.com/GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle
In the docs, there is a page about How to Send a message to a specific user https://github.com/GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle/blob/master/Resources/docs/SessionSetup.md . This method allows you to send a message ONLY to 1 user between all the users that are subscribed to the same channel. You do this by passing the user's username to the function.

This opens a new possiblity: creating only 1 big channel with all the logged in users subscribed to it INSTEAD of creating N channels where N is the number of authenticated users.
In other words, which is better: 1 channel with 1000 subscribers or 1000 channels with 1 subscriber?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a publish/subscribe framework and rely on the implementation of that framework to scale.  You seem to be solving a problem that has been solved many times before.  Search for ActiveMQ publish/subscribe, Kaazing JMS, Kaazing AMQP, Pusher, IBM MQTT/WS, etc.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11132290)

Comment: Just curious Ronak.  Why doesn't it answer the question?   It solves the poster's problem, correct?  Igor is going down a path that will take much energy and unnecessary time.  Using a pub/sub framework will address his problem and allow him to work on the application as opposed to the plumbing.